# how to identify the element that was clicked when adding eventListener in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i'm trying to make a FAQ list where only one question gets expanded at a time, my approatch is to add event listeners in a for loop to all question elements, the problem I can't identify which element got clicked, I know I can add eventlisteners separately but I wanted to learn about this method  :

js code :

```js
var query = document.getElementsByClassName("query");

for (var i = 0 ; i < query.length; i++) {
    
    query[i].addEventListener('click' , function(){
        

        for (var j = 0 ; j < query.length; j++) {
            query[j].classList.remove("active");
            console.log("acitve state removed");
        }

        query[i].classList.add("active");// undefined since "query array is only 0-1 and i = 2 at this stage "
        console.log("activated");
    }) ; 
}
```

html code:

```html
<div class="query">
    <p class="question">How many team members can I invite?</p>
    <img src="/images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="icon-arrow-down">
    <p class="answer">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
        team members for the Premium plan.</p>
</div>
<div class="query">
    <p class="question">What is the maximum file upload size?</p>
    <img src="/images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="icon-arrow-down">
    <p class="answer">  No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
    </p>
</div>
```

console error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Comment: `var` is functionally scoped, try replacing with `let`

Comment: `for (let i = 0...` will fix that right up ... the issue is, by the time `query[i].classList` gets run, i === query.length

Comment: I got some problems with gulp package when using let

Comment: @JaromandaX yes that's what's causing it,, is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Repalce query[i] with this

Comment: if gulp has problems with `let` then it's not worth using :p

Comment: @TusharShahi **thank you sooo much that solved it**

Comment: @anasali glad i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `query[i]` with `this`. this always points to the element on which the event handler is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use `querySelectorAll` to obtain a nodelist you can iterate through that as you would an array and assign the event listener in a slightly different manner that does not rely upon an index as above.

```js
const clickhandler = function(e) {
  let col = document.querySelectorAll('.query');
  col.forEach(n => n.classList.remove('active'))

  this.classList.add('active')
};
document.querySelectorAll('div.query').forEach(n => n.addEventListener('click', clickhandler))
```

```css
.query {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.active {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<div class="query">
  <p class="question">How many team members can I invite?</p>
  <img src="/images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="icon-arrow-down">
  <p class="answer">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="query">
  <p class="question">What is the maximum file upload size?</p>
  <img src="/images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="icon-arrow-down">
  <p class="answer">
    No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked with me in the past for some reason it's not working now

Answer (score 0):

When event listeners are added in a loop, better scope it in an anonymous function or in an external function:

```js
var query = document.getElementsByClassName("query");

for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
  (function(qi, qa) {
    qi.addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var j = 0; j < qa.length; j++) {
        qa[j].classList.remove("active");
        console.log("active state removed");
      }

      qi.classList.add("active");
      console.log("activated");
    })

  })(query[i], query);
}
```

Working:
https://jsfiddle.net/nqkshf3w/

Answer (score 0):

> I got some problems with gulp package when using let –

Personally I would solve the issue with gulp here.

But if you can't use `let` for some reason, then you can scope `var`'s the old way by creating a functionally scoped wrapper.

eg.

```js
//Wrong
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  setTimeout(function () { console.log(i) }, 1);
}

//Correct
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  setTimeout(
    function (i) {
      return function () { console.log(i) };
    }(i)
  ,1);
}
```

Comment: a dependency of gulp is not updated by the author yet so I'm just trying to find another ways till the author publish the updated version